# Is Google/Gmail Deleting emails from Crypto exchange sites like Kraken?

Tags: email, gmail

I was trying to log in to a crypto exchange site that I have not used before but could not as no confirmation emails ever arrived. Troubleshooting led me to the source of the issue, which was Filters set to delete all emails from that domain.

The thing is I never set these filters up! In the screenshot there are some e exchanges I've heard of or even have an account but some I never even heard of so could not have added a filter for.

The question is how did this happen? If someone hacked y account what would be the purpose of this? I really cannot think of the motivation for a third party to delete these emails specifically. I did recently change the password as there was unauthorized access from an app though I saw not other IP's accessing my account so not sure why gmail warned me. Is there anything I am missing?

[image]

Comment: If you are 100% sure you didn't set those filters up, it's possible your email was hacked. I've seen hackers put filters like this in place to prevent the owner of the email account from seeing them doing nefarious things as them other places online. What's strange though is that you never had an account with Kraken (and a hacker didn't set one up for/as you). Google definitely didn't make those filters for you. Unfortunately at this point, it's impossible to say how they were made or who made them.

Comment: You should contact Google with regards to this question.

Comment: I closed this question because the OP is responsible to the filter creation and maintenance, no one can give definitive answer about what happened to the user account settings. By the other hand troubleshooting like questions are not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem is in hacking your account because it could be set by default, so the crypto exchange is the problem, and it was considered to be spam or something like that. Personally, I work with forex after reading this article http://usforexbrokers.com/the-benefits-of-forex-if-you-want-to-become-a-trader-in-the-united-states/, and I can tell you that I've never had an issue like this one with brokers, so I think you shouldn't worry much.